# Where is the cache directory in pip 7.0?

Tags: python, pip

I am using pip version 7.0.3 and python 2.7. When I am installing package, it shows like using cache directory. I want to know location of cache directory. And I am using virtualevn , and pip version 7.0.3. I have searched in location ~/cache/.pip, but the package is not found from the directory . It is referring from some other directory. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I am certain you searched ~/.cache/pip not ~/cache/.pip as stated in your question.

As of version 6 pip now comes with an on-by-default cache functionality which respects your XDG_CACHE_HOME variable. Check it or try /tmp/pip*

Hope that helps.